# How to calculate new column value from two columns and its sum dynamic value in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to add two columns with static value RM500 it gives us a new column called totalSA

**My Table is:**

```
Transaction Date    Pol No.     Policy Status   Incremental SA  Referral SA
16-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100         0
17-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100         0
18-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100         0
18-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100        RM200
19-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100         0
18-Sep-20          P00061354    Inforce             RM100         0
18-Sep-20          P00061354    Inforce             RM100        RM200
19-Sep-20          P00061354    Inforce             RM100         0
```

**Expected Table is:**

```
Transaction Date    Pol No.     Policy Status   Incremental SA  Referral SA  Total SA
16-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100         0           RM600
17-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100         0           RM700
18-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100         0           RM800
18-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100        RM200        RM1100
19-Sep-20          P00061353    Inforce             RM100         0           RM1200
18-Sep-20          P00061354    Inforce             RM100         0           RM600
18-Sep-20          P00061354    Inforce             RM100        RM200        RM900
19-Sep-20          P00061354    Inforce             RM100         0           RM1000
```

**Logic:** if Policy no is the same then we need to increment.

```
(Initial value/previous toal)+Incremental SA + Referral SA   Total SA
      RM500                  +        RM100  +0              RM600 (New Policy)
      RM600                  +        RM100  +0              RM700
      RM700                  +        RM100  +0              RM800
      RM800                  +        RM100  +RM200          RM1100
      RM1100                 +        RM100  +0              RM1200
      RM500                  +        RM100  +0              RM600 (New Policy)
      RM600                  +        RM100  +RM200          RM900
      RM900                  +        RM100  +0              RM1000
```

I have tried the below code doesn't work.

```
Total_SA = 
VAR insSA = CONVERT(SUBSTITUTE([Incremental SA], "RM", ""),INTEGER)
VAR refSA = CONVERT(SUBSTITUTE([Referral SA],"RM",""),INTEGER)


VAR PreviousRow =
    TOPN (
        1,
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Index] < EARLIER('Table'[Index]) && 
             'Table'[Pol No.] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Pol No.])
        ),
        [Index], DESC
    )
 
VAR PreviousValue =  MAXX( PreviousRow,CONVERT(SUBSTITUTE('Table'[Referral SA], "RM", ""),INTEGER)  )  

RETURN  PreviousValue +    CONVERT(SUBSTITUTE('Table'[Incremental SA], "RM", ""),INTEGER) + 500
```

Comment: Replace 0 in referral SA with RM0 and give it a try!

Comment: How do you know the order between the 2 18-sep transactions? Why is it not RM900 and RM1000 instead of your example?

Comment: On the same date also we need to do an increment. that's what we have used index comparison

Comment: Show your index values in the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you have an **Index** column in the table, let your data looks like below-

[image]

Now, create this following **Measure** in the table-

```
total_sa = 

var initial_amount = 500
var current_index = MIN('Table'[Index])

var cumulative_inc_sa = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Incremental SA]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Index] <= current_index
    )
) + 0

var cumulative_ref_sa = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Referral SA]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Index] <= current_index
    )
) + 0

RETURN initial_amount + cumulative_inc_sa + cumulative_ref_sa
```

Here is your final output-

[image]

Comment: The syntax for 'Table' is incorrect. (DAX(var initial_amount = 500var current_index = MIN(Table[Index])var cumulative_inc_sa = CALCULATE( SUM(Table[Incremental SA]), FILTER( ALL(Table), Table[Index] <= current_index )) + 0var cumulative_ref_sa = CALCULATE( SUM(Table[Referral SA]), FILTER( ALL(Table), Table[Index] <= current_index )) + 0RETURN initial_amount + cumulative_inc_sa + cumulative_ref_sa)). <----- Getting this error.

Comment: Replace Table from the code with your original table name. I have used Table as your code shows the name is Table :)

Comment: My table name also Table, still issues.

Comment: Hi @KARTHIKEYAN.A, can you check now? I have updated the answer and put single quote besides the table name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223079/discussion-between-karthikeyan-a-and-r-r).

Answer (score 0):

From your example and assuming that all transactions are sorted by index, that looks like a simple running total:

```
Total_SA =
VAR currentIndex = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Index])
RETURN
 CONCATENATE("RM",
    CONVERT(
       CALCULATE(SUM(CONVERT(SUBSTITUTE('Table'[Incremental SA], "RM", ""),INTEGER)) 
               + SUM(CONVERT(SUBSTITUTE('Table'[Referral SA], "RM", ""),INTEGER)),
         ALL('Table'),
         'Table'[Index] <= currentIndex
       ) + 500, STRING))
```

I would recommend that you create 2 additional columns with the int value of the SAs, as it would make the code a bit more readable.

Comment: What's the error? Is that index an ascending primary key?

Comment: ```Total_SA = 
VAR currentIndex = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Index])
RETURN IF('Table'[Index] = 1,
 CONCATENATE("RM",
    CONVERT(
       CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Incremental SA]) 
               + SUM('Table'[Referral SA]),
         ALL('Table'),
         'Table'[Index] <= currentIndex
       ) + 500, STRING)),CONCATENATE("RM",
    CONVERT(
       CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Incremental SA]) 
               + SUM('Table'[Referral SA]),
         ALL('Table'),
         'Table'[Index] <= currentIndex
       ), STRING)))``` Trying this also not working